# Wrong date_create_from_format 'jmy'

Tags: php

I need to import date in format `'jmy'` and output it to the other format, but this function is returning wrong date:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('jmy', '10114');
echo date_format($date, 'd.m.Y');
```

I am awaiting **01.01.2014** from it, but it returns **10.11.2004**. When I tried `'j.m.y'` I've got correct result. Problem is, that I can't change input from imported data and I need it as described.

Comment: That date format just may be too ambiguous to work with

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, I agree. But when I have 'j' for day in month with no leading zeros, I am awaiting that function will understand and accept it. Next digits will be always four (certainly in life on this application), so what can be confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure that your input gets left-padded with zeros using [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
php > $date = date_create_from_format('jmy', sprintf('%06s', '10114'));
php > echo date_format($date, 'd.m.Y') . "\n";
01.01.2014
```